# Implicit Meanings/Interpretations of を

Tags: meaning, particle-を

I need some help reasoning out the implied meaning of を in a song lyric. The lines in question are:

何{なに}もかもが隠{かく}された　この世界{せかい}で生{い}きるよ 僕{ぼく}だけの輝{かがや}きを

I'm a little shaky on how を should be interpreted in cases like these where it just sort of trails off the sentence. What's a good way to interpret these situations for meaning? In what way is を showing that 輝{かがや}き is an object?

Comment: It seems that it's a little *poetic* expression. I mean, there's no pre-defined choice for this sort of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence omits `生きるよ` at the end of the sentence.
So, complete sentence will be `何もかも隠されたこの世界で生きるよ。僕だけの輝きを生きるよ。`.

The speaker of this sentence thinks that the world is clouded.
But at the same time, the speaker sets his mind on living the world in his shining way.